# Powering 4 12V 0.45Amp fans off USB?

Tags: converter, diy, undervoltage

This question actually has a few parts.

Basically I have 4 12V 0.45 A computer fans,which I want to use in a DIY cooling pad project I'm currently working on. I know that as per the standard USB 2.0 spec, all I'll get out of my laptop is 5V and 0.5 A. I've read about DC step-up converters, would they be suitable for getting the required 12V the fans need for full speed? Can the fans run at all with the limited output current they'll get? Is there any way at all I can run these on full speed off a USB port?

I also wanted to have a physical control of some kind for the fan speed, can I use a simple potentiometer for this?

Comment: nope, the numbers are not even close to work, even for a single fan. You will be better off by building an independent power supply for those fans and leaving the usb port alone

Comment: Power out of the DC-DC converter will always be less than power in, due to less than 100% efficiency. Power is Volts * Amps, so your USB will provide at most 2.5W. You can work out the power needed for your fans, is it more than 2.5W?

Comment: Regarding the "I also wanted to have a physical control of some kind for the fan speed, can I use a simple potentiometer for this?" that no one has addressed so far. **NO**. It's too inefficient => too much heat will be generated in the potentiometer, and it will most certainly break.

Comment: Does not make sense to dream about 4 (four) fans and then wanting to control the speed (probably down). If you follow Claudio's advice and get a proper power supply, then you could just install four switches and run any number of fans from 0 to 4 and have not speed control but at least "fan control" with minimal cost and no trouble figuring out the "physics".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The piece of knowledge missing is the relationship between voltage, current and power, \$ P = VI \$.

From this we can work out:

- One fan will require \$ P = VI = 12 \times 0.45 = 5.4 \; W \$.
- Four fans will require \$ 4 \times 5.4 = 21.6 \;W \$.
- Your USB port can supply \$ P = VI = 5 \times 0.5 = 2.5 \; W \$.

You haven't enough power to run one fan. Introduce a boost converter with an efficiency of, say, 85% and the situation becomes that much worse.

Comment: Let's not forget to mention that with a boost converter, you push more current in than you get out, that's even with 100% efficiency. Because if this equation must be true: \$P_{in}=P_{out}\$, and your \$V_{out} > V_{in}\$, then this equation must also be true: \$I_{in}>I_{out}\$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Better off using an AC-DC adapter to get all the current and voltage I need then.

Comment: @Abj If you got a desktop computer, then there's most likely a spare 12V connector from the PSU that most likely can deliver the power you need.

Comment: @HarrySvensson - Your comment about a desktop computer is not relevant as the OP states that they are working with a laptop,

Comment: @MichaelKaras It was made for a laptop, but per haps Abj got a regular PSU from some _old_ desktop computer which he/she can take for free, rather than buying another PSU.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Reading OP again I'd say he's trying to cool the laptop but he may have access to a fixed supply if his cooling pad stays in one place.